# HOW To set htaccess to enable embed in iframe from another website

Tags: permissions, .htaccess, html

I have these 2 servers, one with virtual tour folder in it
eg:

1st server: `somevirtualserver.com/vr/propertygood`

then other server: `virtualviewer.com/virtualpage/index.html`

and I want to embed it in an `iframe` tag html
but then I get message

> Can’t Open This Page

inside the iframe, so i guess there might be a htaccess setup to enable

here is the code in virtualviewer.com/virtualpage/index.html:

```
<iframe id="inlineFrameExample"
    title="Inline Frame Example"
    width="300"
    height="200"
    src="somevirtualserver.com/vr/propertygood">
</iframe>
```

the result is

[image: result]

**EDIT:**

Not sure this is right:

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM=*
```

Is there a way in htaccess to enable embedding from another website?

Comment: Please check the developer tools of your browser for a more detailed error message. With the current information we can't even guess.

Comment: And, tell us what you've tried.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, updated dude, any comment appreciate it
had tried to config htaaccess ans still no luck

Comment: @JayChou In what way did you try to "config htaaccess"?

Comment: @MrWhite
not sure this is right 

Header always append X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM=*
that is why i asked about it here, is there a way in htaccess ?? to enable embedding from another website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You need to set the X-Frame-Option to allow to embed the page.

You can do this in a .htaccess file, but only if Apache is configured to allow it. If the Apache configuration does not allow Header directives in the .htaccess file and you don't have control over the Apache config you are out of luck. However, if you can edit the Apache config you should add it there instead of the .htaccess file.

You need to configure this on the server where the page that should be embedded resides, in your case `somevirtualserver.com`.

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM virtualviewer.com
```

Comment: thx 4 your lead dude i was thought it would be simpler, if we define it in htaccess instead changing it under etc/apache2 folder

Answer (score 3):

I've completed this by setting apache config on my ubuntu under security.conf so it won't mess another directory and malicious embed

```
<Directory /var/www/rootweb/html/public/vr/virtualserving>
    Header always unset X-Frame-Options
</Directory>
```